# Set the Data of a Spinner based on a result of previous Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-studio, spinner

I'm trying to fill a spinner based on a choice in a previous spinner,and I'm trying to get the id of the selected item in the previous spinner and the with an if statement I'm trying to add data to the another spinner.The string array are define in the Strings.xml.Any Help Please and this is my code.

```
public class Set_Info extends AppCompatActivity {
int i;
RadioButton btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set__info);

    final EditText CompanyName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.companyName);
    final EditText OwnerName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ownerName);
    final Spinner CompanyType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.companyType);
    final Spinner Mohafaza = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerMohafaza);
    final Spinner Kadaa = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerKadaa);
    final EditText Village = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.village);
    final EditText Street = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.street);
    final EditText PhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
    final EditText PolicyNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.policyNumber);
    final DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    final TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    final EditText AuditName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.auditName);
    final EditText AuditNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.auditNumber);
    final RadioGroup RadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio);
    if(RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()!=-1){
        int id= RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        View Rd = RadioGroup.findViewById(id);
        int radioId = RadioGroup.indexOfChild(Rd);
        RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) RadioGroup.getChildAt(radioId);
    }
    final List<String> Facilities = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Facilities));
    ArrayAdapter<String> FaciltiesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_style, Facilities);

    final List<String> Mohafazat = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Mohafazat));
    ArrayAdapter<String> MohazatAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_style, Mohafazat);

    CompanyType.setAdapter(FaciltiesAdapter);
    Mohafaza.setAdapter(MohazatAdapter);

    final List<String> KadaaBeirut = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.KadaaBeirut));
    final List<String> KadaaJabal = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.KadaaJabal));
    final List<String> KadaaNorth = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.KadaaNorth));
    final List<String> KadaaSouth = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.KadaaSouth));
    final List<String> KadaaNabatieh = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.KadaaNabatieh));
    final List<String> KadaaBekaa = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.KadaaBekaa));
    ;
    final ArrayAdapter<String> BeirutAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_style,KadaaBeirut);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> JabalAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_style,KadaaJabal);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> NorthAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_style,KadaaNorth);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> SouthAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_style,KadaaSouth);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> NabatiehAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_style,KadaaNabatieh);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> BekaaAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_style,KadaaBekaa);

    Mohafaza.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             i = parent.getSelectedItemPosition();

        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
    if(i==0){
        Kadaa.setAdapter(BeirutAdapter);
    }else if(i==1){
        Kadaa.setAdapter(JabalAdapter);
    }else if(i==2){
        Kadaa.setAdapter(NorthAdapter);
    }else if(i==3){
        Kadaa.setAdapter(SouthAdapter);
    }else if(i==4){
        Kadaa.setAdapter(NabatiehAdapter);
    }else if(i==5){
        Kadaa.setAdapter(BekaaAdapter);
    }
    Button Submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    final ParseObject data = new ParseObject("General_Data");
    Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            data.put("CompanyName", CompanyName.getText().toString().trim());
            data.put("OwnerName", OwnerName.getText().toString().trim());
            data.put("CompanyType", CompanyType.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
            data.put("Mohafaza", Mohafaza.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
            data.put("Kadaa", Kadaa.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
            data.put("Village", Village.getText().toString().trim());
            data.put("Street", Street.getText().toString().trim());
            data.put("PhoneNumber", PhoneNumber.getText().toString().trim());
            data.put("PolicyNumber", PolicyNumber.getText().toString().trim());
            data.put("AuditName", AuditName.getText().toString().trim());
            data.put("AuditNumber", AuditNumber.getText().toString().trim());
            data.put("Inspect_Type",btn.getText().toString());


            data.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Set_Info.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

                }
            });
}
}
```

Comment: The class needs to be called `SetInfo`, or better yet, `InfoSetter`, not `Set_Info`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice...I will change the name...but I want to fix the spinner issue first

Comment: i think use if else condition inside the spinner listener